# Swift Mailer doesn't send the email?

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I use Swift Mailer in Symfony 2, It appears in the profile bar that the email has been sent but it seems it was not.

Controller :

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('koorahome@gmail.com')
            ->setTo('hzweb4@gmail.com')
            ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                    // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                    'verify/email.html.twig', array()
            ), 'text/html'
            )
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Paramaters :

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: koorahome@gmail.com
mailer_password: *******
```

Comment: Why not use the `mailer_transport: gmail` option for SwiftMailer? Also, I'm not sure that the profiler checks the email was actually accepted when sending. Perhaps you have two configurations for SwiftMailer in your Symfony app and one is sending to an address your not checking? Is SwiftMailer, in dev env, set to not actually send email?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your setting need set as your server problem. I mean you need to set sender same as your server.

For example, your server `http://example.com` than you need to create mail in your server as: `name@example.com` see your config in your server mail and set it in your SwiftMailer.

If your server is `localhost` and want to test email, use mailtrap : https://mailtrap.io/. Register, create mail test, see config for symfony and setup.

Answer (score -1):

Check your Gmail settings. You may have to allow SMTP emails.

Try below:

Log into your Gmail or Google Apps email Settings and click on the Forwarding/IMAP tab. Scroll down to the IMAP Access section. IMAP must be enabled in order for emails to be properly copied to your sent folder.